# Flutter build failed stuck in 'pod install’ while trying to implement cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

After completing https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5 these code lab steps successfully. I tried to run the app. But it is stuck in the ‘pod install’ command. When I try to find the error opening the workspace in Xcode and attempted to run from there and I found a error message. It says the **Cloud Firestore Plugin.h missing?**

pls See the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: try to go into the PROJECT_DIR/ios folder and run pod install

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Podfile.lock` open command line tool and navigate to iOS folder of your flutter app.
Run `pod install` from command line tool. Verify all the pods are installed successfully.

Hope this helps!